# Runtime error - Non-exhaustive patterns in function

Tags: haskell, runtime-error

I want to write a function which prints out a list of numbers from 1 to n:  [1,2,...n], I know it can be done by `[1..n]` but I want to make my own function:

```
addtimes n = addtimes_ [] n
addtimes_ [lst] a =
    if a < 1 
    then [lst]
    else  addtimes_ [a:lst] (a-1)
main = 
    print $ addtimes 10
```

Though above code compiles and runs, it gives following runtime error:

```
testing: testing.hs:(3,1)-(6,37): Non-exhaustive patterns in function addtimes_
```

Where is the problem and how can it be solved?

Comment: You've only defined the function for a singleton list: `[lst]` means a list of one element, which you are referring to as `lst` in the function body. If `lst` is supposed to mean the entire list, as it seems, just replace `[lst]` by `lst` everywhere.

Comment: Enabling warnings would spot this at compile time, and report the cases you are not handling (lists of length /= 1). Strongly recommended.

Comment: How do I enable warnings? I could not find any option in `ghc --help` output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the following, with corrected syntax (and type signatures added, seriously these are essential for both code documentation and for better error messages):

```
addtimes :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> [a]
addtimes n = addtimes_ [] n

addtimes_ :: (Num a, Ord a) => [a] -> a -> [a]
addtimes_ lst a =
    if a < 1 
    then lst
    else  addtimes_ (a:lst) (a-1)

main :: IO ()
main = 
    print $ addtimes 10
```

As well as referring to `[lst]` (a singleton list containing the one element `lst`) instead of `lst` (which can refer to anything, which in the context of your function must be a list, but can be of any length), you had put `[a:lst]` (again a singleton list, this time containing a list) instead of `(a:lst)`, a list made up of first element `a` appended to the front of `lst`. (The parentheses are not needed for any syntactic reason, but are usually needed in practice, as in the above code, because of operator precedence: `addtimes_ a:list (a-1)` would be parsed as `(addtimes_ a):(list (a-1))`, which definitely isn't what you mean.

Comment: as an example of what I mean about type signature, pasting in your original code, and asking GHCI to tell me the type of `addtimes` with `:t addtimes` produces the result `(Ord t, Num t) => t -> [[t]]`. That is, your version returns a list of lists, not a list of "plain elements" as you intended. If you'd have included the type signature (and don't worry too much about the `(Ord a, Num a)` stuff if you don't understand it yet, `Int -> [Int]` would have been fine for your purposes), then you'd have got a type error from that function.

Comment: I get the usefulness of adding signatures.

Answer (score 1):

> Edit:

To achieve what you want, now I understand your goal reading your

```
addtimes :: Int -> [Int]
addtimes 0       = []
addtimes n       = if n > 0
                   then addtimes_ 1 n
                   else error "Doesn't work with negatives"

addtimes_ :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
addtimes_ m n = if n > m
                then m : (addtimes_ (m+1) n) 
                else [n]

main = 
    print $ addtimes (10)
```

That will create a list with the numbers adding 1 consecutively

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```